# Need help proving that the first moment of the entire area of a cross section with respect to its own centroid will be zero.

Tags: calculus, integration, area, classical-mechanics, multiple-integral

If I take a rectangle of length $a$ and height $h$, then the first moment of area $A$ about the $x$-axis is

$$Q_x=\int y\,dA=\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}y \, dx dy = 0$$

Similarly, I can also show that about the $y$-axis we have $Q_y=0$.

I have trouble showing $Q_z=0$. I am taking $$Q_z=\int\int r\, dx dy = \int \int \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dxdy.$$

I have no idea what the limits of integration should be. I was wondering if anyone can help me out with this. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Why is $Q_z$ an integration of $r$?

Comment: @Andrei: Well, I was thinking it would be a polar-type situation, since there are three axes involved. If this isn't how it should be done, what other way is there?

Comment: @Andrei: Another approach that's coming to my mind is to fix either $x=0$ or $y=0$, in which case I can see that the limits of integration would come out to be similar to the above and then the integral would turn out to be zero, but I'm not so sure about this and at this point I'm just guessing what the method should be to get the result that I want... not the usual way of doing mathematics, I realize.

Comment: You should start from the definition of the cross section. It is a figure in a plane. So for your problem, if the rectangle is at some $z_0$, parallel to the $xy$ plane, you need to integrate $z(x,y)-z_0$. Since $z(x,y)=z_0$, you just integrate $0$.

Comment: @Andrei: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I don't get why I need to integrate $z(x, y)-z_0$? I'm also confused as to why the function $z(x, y)=z_0$?

Comment: Please explain what the cross section is. For me it's the intersection of a 3D object with a 2D plane. You just took a rectangle. Where is that rectangle?

Comment: @Andrei: I wanted to say that I thought about this for a few days and couldn't convince myself if I understood what you were saying. I was hoping you would provide an answer to this question and help me with it. Mechanics isn't my subject and I did look around if any book would contain the answer to this problem but couldn't find anything. This isn't my homework or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(geometry))

> "In geometry and science, a cross section is the non-empty intersection of a solid body in three-dimensional space with a plane"

So you have a figure in a plane, not necessarily through the origin.

The statement in the title is true in a more general sense, for any number of dimensions. Let's suppose we have a 3D object, with a constant density $\rho$, spanning a region $V$ in space. The mass of the object is $$M=\rho\iiint_V dV=\rho\iiint_V dx dy dz$$
The coordinates of the center of mass are $$\begin{align}x_c&=\frac{\rho}M\iiint _Vxdxdydz\\y_c&=\frac{\rho}M\iiint _Vyxdxdydz\\z_c&=\frac{\rho}M\iiint _Vzdxdydz\end{align}$$

The moment with respect to a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is given by $$Q_x(x_0)=\iiint_V(x-x_0)dx dy dz$$
and similar for $y$ and $z$.

Now let's choose $x_0=x_c$. $$\begin{align}Q_x(x_c)&=\iiint_V(x-x_c)dx dy dz\\ &=\iiint_Vxdx dy dz-\iiint_Vx_cdx dy dz\\&=x_c\frac{M}{\rho}-x_c\iiint_Vdxdydz\\&=x_c\frac{M}{\rho}-x_c\frac{M}{\rho}\\&=0\end{align}$$

You can do similarly for $y$ and $z$ components.

This will apply to a planar figure in 3D as well. The density will contain a delta function, to limit it to a surface density. Then the integration volume can be transformed into a 2D integration area through a clever choice in change of variables, and you don't care about the direction perpendicular to the plane. What I mean by this, suppose that your cross section is in a plane parallel to the $xy$ plane, but located at $z=z_0$. Then the center of mass must be in the plane at $z_0$. Then the $z-z_0$ term for all the points is zero.

Let's assume that we have only a figure in the $xy$ plane, so we can ignore the $z$ direction. Say we have a rectangle, with axes parallel to the $x$ (from $x_0$ to $x_1$) and $y$ (from $y_0$ to $y_1$) axes. Then $$\begin{align}A&=\int_{x_0}^{x_1} dx\int_{y_0}^{y_1}dy=(x_1-x_0)(y_1-y_0)\\x_c&=\frac 1A\int_{x_0}^{x_1} xdx\int_{y_0}^{y_1}dy\\&=\frac 1{(x_1-x_0)(y_1-y_0)}\left(\frac{x_1^2}2-\frac{x_0^2}2\right)(y_1-y_0)\\&=\frac{x_1+x_0}2\\Q_x&=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}(x-x_c)dx\int_{y_0}^{y_1}dy\\&=\left(\frac{x_1^2}2-\frac{x_0^2}2\right)(y_1-y_0)-x_c(x_1-x_0)(y_1-y_0)\\&=0\end{align}$$ 
You can do similarly for $y_c$ and $Q_y$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I wanted to ask for some simplification, though, if that's not too much trouble. In the simpler case when I was working in 2D space, I wasn't taking into consideration $M$ and $\rho$, nor the coordinates of the center of mass. Say I wanted to this answer to return to simpler times (2D space, as in the OP), how would I go about doing that? I'm asking because I don't quite get where you're getting the values for $M$ and $x_c$ from, for example.

Comment: And I'm not saying your answer is incomplete in any way: you're addressing precisely what I'm asking for in the end of the answer. I just wish that similar to the way you explained the math in the generalized setting, you would also explain mathematically (by showing some of the working, evaluating the integrals, etc.) the particular situation in this question. Thanks again regardless for your help.

Comment: The centroid is the center of mass when $\rho=1$, therefore $M=V$. I will add the 2D case to the answer